# SplitViewTemplate, so I got that error is does not exit in a namespace

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, uwp

```
<Page
    x:Class="MutiViewInRootPage.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MutiViewInRootPage"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:control="using:MutiViewInRootPage.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

 <DataTemplate x:Key="NavMenuItemTemplate" x:DataType="local:NavMenuItem">
```

local:NavMenuItem does not exit namspace

```
<control:NavMenuListView x:Name="NavMenuList"
                                             Grid.Row="1"
                                             ItemsSource="{x:Bind NavList}"
                                             ContainerContentChanging="NavMenuItemContrinerContentChanging"
                                             ItemInvokded="NavMenuList_ItemInvoked"
                                             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavMenuItemTemplate}"/>
```

control:NavMenuListView does not exit... namespace.

Base on https://github.com/jamesmcroft/Windows-Universal-SplitViewTemplate/tree/master/AppTemplate

I did it such as SplitViewTemplate but does not exit... namespace.
 I can't fix this problem.

Comment: There is no mention of the `NavMenuListView` in the linked repository.

Comment: Base on sample, I write it for myself. So I put different name but code is same.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please make sure the namespace of `NavMenuListView` is correct (it is very common that people copied the codes or file but forgot to modify the namespace):
[image]

Secondly, if the namespace is correct, but the error persists, try compiling the project. Sometimes XAML compiler doesn't recognize the new control before compiling. After compiling, the error will be gone.

If the error still exists, could you please share the project through a online repository?

**Update:** I downloaded the demo project and try building the whole project. And found `NavMenuList_ItemInvoked` isn't implemented. So I added the following codes in code-behind:

```
private void NavMenuList_ItemInvoked(object sender, ListViewItem e){}
```

Then the build went through successfully.

Comment: Link on GitHub :[https://github.com/Englbach/MutiViewInRootPage](https://github.com/Englbach/MutiViewInRootPage)

Comment: I've updated the answer. It turns out  the `NavMenuList_ItemInvoked` isn't implemented. Writing an empty eventhandler and building again fixed the issue.